# Matlab Convolution 'same'

Tags: matlab, convolution

I read Matlab documentation about convolution and i have found this :

```
u = [-1 2 3 -2 0 1 2]; v = [2 4 -1 1]; w = conv(u,v,'same')
```

And the answer is

```
 w = 15     5    -9     7     6     7    -1
```

Do you know how was w calculated? I know how you calculate the normal convolution product, but what about this?

Thank you for you help in advance !

Comment: It seems your example was taken straight from the [`conv` documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html). Is there something you didn't understand from there?

Comment: Yes it was, how was w calculated? :( I don't understand how they get this result. Sorry for my bad English !

Comment: `z = conv(u,v)` would normally give you `z = [-2 0 15 5 -9 7 6 7 -1 2]`. The `same` option forces the result to be the same size as `u`, which has `7` elements. Since `z` has `10` elements, we just take the inner `7` elements of `z` to get `w`. The result is `w = [15 5 -9 7 6 7 -1]`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you determine from which inner element to start ? Is it   kernel.size/2 + 1?

Comment: From a couple experiments, you appear to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the above answer is almost correct, except for the misplaced u and v in the last line of the code. That is:

```
w = w_full(floor(length(v)/2) + (1:length(u))); % 'same' like convolution
```

After all, the length of the output is the same as the length of u, not v.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your question is how to determine the limits of the convolution when shape is set to 'same'. From the 'full' shape convolution provided by Matlab, 'same' subvector can be calculated as follows:

```
u = [-1 2 3 -2 0 1 2];
v = [2 4 -1 1];
w = conv(u,v,'same');

w_full = conv(u,v,'full'); % full size (zero-padded) convolution
w = w_full(floor(length(u)/2) + (1:length(v))); % 'same' like convolution
```